# Error: INSERT INTO MySQLi

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

Estoy creando un pequeño formulario pero me lanza el siguiente error

```sql
Error: INSERT INTO alumno (nombre,edad) VALUES ['Juan','25'] You have
an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
'['Juan','25']' at line 1
```

Si me pudieran ayudar seria de gran ayuda gracias.

*index.html:*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="Insertar.php"> 
      Nombre : <input type="text" name="nombre"><br> 
      Edad : <input type="text" name="edad"><br> 
      <br> 
      <br><br> 
      <input type="submit" name="valider" value="Enviar"> 
    </form> 

  </body>
</html>
```

*Insertar.php:*

```
<?php
//Datos de la base de datos
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "alumnos";

//creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, "") or die
    ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

//Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die 
    ("Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

//recuperacion de variables
$NOMBRE=$_POST["nombre"];
$EDAD=$_POST["edad"];

//Registrar nueva entrada
$sql = "INSERT INTO alumno (nombre,edad) VALUES [$NOMBRE,$EDAD]";
if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)){
    echo "Nuevo alumno registrado";
}else{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexion);
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: no son corchetes, sino parentesis los que debes usar

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis despues de values, debe de ser INSERT INTO alumno (nombre,edad) VALUES ($NOMBRE,$EDAD)

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO alumno (nombre,edad) VALUES [$NOMBRE,$EDAD]";
```

Por:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO alumno (nombre,edad) VALUES ($NOMBRE,$EDAD)";
```

Presta atención a los paréntesis, los corchetes no aplican.